# Restore a removed branch in CVS

Tags: tags, branch, cvs, restore, tortoisecvs

By mistake I removed the branch name of a file using TortoiseCVS.
I think this can be reproduced using the standard cvs client with this command :

```
cvs tag -d -B <mybranch> <myfile>
```

How do I restore it ?

*I tried the following things :*

- Add the branch to the last revision
- Add the branch to the last tag (in my case this is also the last revision)

In either way, a new branch is started and the revision numbering is changed (6 numbers instead of 4). This is not acceptable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose the revision numbering of the file is of the form 1.1.2.x

Then use this command (you don't need to do a checkout beforehand)

```
cvs rtag -r 1.1.2 <mybranch> <module/path/to/my/file>
```